# How to config the APS at Developer website

Tags: ios

When  I build my Demo app ,the General page shows the error. 
I am trying to config the APS at Developer website,but I can't find the Certificates Page.I just want to run the demo on my own iPhone for test.
Should I Pay 99$ for my account?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not deploy your Apple ID and development certificate.

Since Xcode 7, every Apple ID has a free development certificate to use. [Here is a tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingAccounts/ManagingAccounts.html) about how to deploy a free development certificate.

Free certificate does not require a registered device ID. Some application services will be limited to use for free certificate, such as Push Notifications, In-App Purchase, Apple Pay etc.

---

### I have created a new Apple ID to test a bit, the steps are as follows

#### Generate a free development certificate

Preferences -> Account -> Add Apple ID -> Manage Certificates -> Add iOS Development

#### Debugging using device

Plug in device to start debugging.

#### Untrusted developers

Open Settings on device and navigate to General -> Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.

#### Still does not work

If still prompted **Failed to create provisioning profile**. Change your bundle identifier to a special string to try again such as `com.test.test` to `com.qwer.asdf`.

Comment: I have add my account at the Acount Page.But the capabilities are limited for a free account? Such as apple push service can't open?  How to register my device id ?